# CSS - Restricting top property value to 0 on zoom for a dialog

Tags: html, css, dialog

In our UI, when we click on a link a dialog gets opened.

Now if trying to zoom ( Pressing ctrl and + ) on the page. Dialog starts getting truncated from top as it gets out of the browser's window and even not scrollable.

**Cause**

When we zoom in, css `top` property value keep on decreasing and when it gets negative then it keeps on truncating the top view of dialog.

**Dialog CSS**

It's inline CSS of the element.

```
element.style {
   position: absolute;
   height: auto;
   width: 600px;
   display: block;
   top: 279px;
   left: 661px;
   z-index: 10002;
}
```

**Possible solutions which I am avoiding**

1. In parent's CSS class, add property top as `top: 0px !important` so that dialog element's top property wouldn't be able to override it.
2. Add polling concept and after every second keep on changing the top property of dialog element.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra I added inline CSS of dialog element.

Comment: @AjayYadav please share HTML too, please. If we can reproduce the problem we might be able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use

> top : 1rem;

It will automatically adjust.

When we zoom into our browser it behaves as different devices. For eg: If we zoom at level 175% the pixel width of our screen size is 732px .

Check
[relation between zooming and pixel width](http://mqtest.io/)

For more customized help please share your code snippet :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am probably missing some knowledge regarding CSS. I tried to set property top to  1rem as you have suggested but during zoom operation, it automatically gets changed to pixels 'px'.

Comment: try changing position: absolute; to position: relative;   as absolute position is overlooked by following  elements.